# Facebook API read and publish

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, libgdx

I need to give my users read and publish permissions on authentication. The publish is used to published their score which is also saved on facebook. I am using the following code snippet for authentication.

```
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            loginResult.getAccessToken().getPermissions();
            nextActivity(profile);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {      }
    };

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        backtogame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backtogame);
        backtogame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);



           // if (isLoggedIn()) {
               // Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                //nextActivity(profile);
           // }

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
                }
            };

            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                    nextActivity(newProfile);
                }
            };

            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();

            callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    nextActivity(profile);
                }



                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error, Check your internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };


                loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends", "user_games_activity");
                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
        }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Facebook login

            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            // loginButton.clearPermissions();
            // loginButton.setPublishPermissions("publish_actions");   //write permissions should be set after read permission, and need to change category on facebook to game
            nextActivity(profile);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Facebook login
            accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
            profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        //Facebook login
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    }
```

In case i add the "publish_actions" permissions to the loginbutton, it will not ask for the read permissions anymore.

All the articles that i've found online are related to a session parameter which is not being used anymore.

Comment: you should not ask for read and write permissions on login. only ask for write permissions when you finally need it. and make sure not to autopost.

Comment: @luschn i will need it on login..

Comment: what for? do you post something on login directly? the proper way would be to use the login at the beginning with read permissions, then let the user play the game, and then let the user authorize publish permission for the score when the game is over.

Comment: @luschn i want to publish his top score directly. If a user has a top score and did not previously login to facebook, then he authenticated his account, i need to set his top score to be the score on facebook, even if he stopped playing the game after logging into facebook